# React Masonry Grid with infinite scrolling breaks

Tags: css, reactjs, reddit, react-query

I have a problem with Masonry grid breaking after scrolling for a while, like in this GIF. Firefox works perfectly.

[GIF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GCuRB.gif)

Here is codesandbox with example.

https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-nash-y337c?file=/src/App.js

Data is coming from reddit API using React-Query.

```
const queryPosts = async (key, nextId = "") => {
const { data } = await Axios.get(
  `https://www.reddit.com/r/earthporn/hot.json?
  &after=` + nextId
);

return {
  data: data,
  nextId: data.data.after
  };
};


//GET DATA

const {
  status,
  data,
  error,
  isFetching,
  isFetchingMore,
  fetchMore,
  canFetchMore,
  isLoading
  } = useInfiniteQuery("infinite-posts", queryPosts, {
  getFetchMore: ({ data, nextId }) => {
    return nextId;
  }
});
```

After fetching, I check for post type (image or text post) which is then rendered according to post type. After Image or Text is loaded I am automatically seting spans depending on image or meta text height. I am automatically setting spans depending on image height.

```
const hasImage = () => {
 if (post.preview) {
  return true;
 } else {
  return false;
 }
}; 

useEffect(() => {
//IF post has image, set grid spans according to image height and meta text height, if not, just take height of meta and render.
if (hasImage()) {
  //This allows browser to get image height after it is loaded. It displayed as "0" before that,       because it tried to get data when the image was not loaded.
  //We need to wait for image to load, then set spans.
  imageRef?.current?.addEventListener("load", () => {
    setSpans(
      Math.ceil(
        (imageRef?.current?.clientHeight + metaRef?.current?.clientHeight) /
          10 +
          1
      )
    );
  });

} else {
  //We don't need to wait for text to load, so just set spans.
  setSpans(Math.ceil(metaRef?.current?.clientHeight / 10 + 1));
}
}, [imageRef, metaRef]);
```

It works as intended on firefox, but others break after scrolling for a while.
When I use external packages, scrolling is not buggy but I am not happy with how it looks.

Help :(

Comment: You need to decrease the amount of rows drawn to avoid reaching browsers limit https://codesandbox.io/s/still-darkness-i6wxx to tune to your needs

Comment: Thanks, however I can't see the difference...Still works same. Could you please clarify?

Comment: sorry, change were not forked : https://codesandbox.io/s/elastic-rhodes-il14x?file=/src/Posts.js (row set to 100px and height divided by 100 instead 10 , instead 10 rows  of 10px, you have only one of 100px. height before the limit is reached is 10 times bigger, but numbers of max rows remains the same . the idea is to remain below that max numbers of rows that can be handle by the browser.

Comment: Ah, thank you so much. So the grid breaks because chrome has 1000 rows limit... I just realized that. When I scroll for long enough it still breaks, but at least now I know what is the deeper issue. Maybe I shouln't do that with grid, but it is the only way I found that looks okay. Thanks!

Comment: you could try with column-count, but you'll have to manage reordering item position ... else, break it into new grid containers every 999 rows :( or remove the first rows to keep the whole grid always below the 999 limit